# Simplify the characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am taking my first math exam in a long time in linear algebra tomorrow. I have a feeling theres for sure going to be a question to find eigenvalues and their eigenvectors. I can do almost all of this fine, except simplifying the characteristic polynomial to actually find the eigenvalues. Is there any simple methods/tricks I can use to find the eigenvalues from the polynomial?

Many thanks

Comment: It depends on the given matrix. Sometimes, it is easy to guess an eigenvalue, but in this case, you can guess the root of the polynomial as well. If you know one root, you can apply polynomial division to reduce the degree.

Comment: There is nothing special in finding the roots of a *characteristic* polynomial.  However sometimes it is possible to find some (or even all) eigenvalues of a matrix without solving the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: I hope and suspect that on an exam you will see polynomials where it's easy to guess the roots. The point of the question should be to test what you know about linear algebra, not factoring.

Comment: I just got this polynomial: https://imgur.com/a/3CKthTw
I have no idea how to proceed from here. How do I "guess" the roots?

Answer (score 0):

As people have mentioned in the comments, it could be wise to find some eigenvalues first, and then apply polynomial division to get a simpler polynomial. Here are some tricks to help you out (make sure you know how to prove these too):

- If the matrix is not invertible, it has $0$ as an eigenvalue (though that might not be very helpful in simplifying the characteristic polynomial).
- If the sum of each row of the matrix is equal to $k$, then $k$ is an eigenvalue, with a corresponding eigenvector - $$\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\...\\1\end{array}\right)$$
- The sum of eigenvalues is equal to the trace of the matrix.
- The product of eigenvalues is equal to the determinant of the matrix.
- If you have a real matrix with a certain complex number as an eigenvalue, then you must also have its complex conjugate as an eigenvalue (and the corresponding eigenvector will be the same vector, with conjugate entries).
- To simplify a polynomial, it is good to be familiar with Vieta's formulas.
- Another useful trait of polynomials - if $k$ is a root of a polynomial, and also of its derivative, then it is of at least multiplicity $2$ (and inductively, you can keep doing this until it is no longer a root of the n-th derivative).

Hope some of these help!